Problem with evaluating $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+x$ by factoring $x^2$ from the radical
I have a question, excuse me if it is too simple for your understanding.
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+x&=\infty-\infty\\
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{x^2\left(1-\frac2x+\frac3{x^2}\right)}+x
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}x\left(\sqrt{1-\frac2x+\frac3{x^2}}+1\right)\\
&=-\infty \times 2 \\
&= -\infty
\end{align*}$$
I have been told that to find the limit of a function with a square root I need to multiply by the conjugate. But why cannot I do it this other way?
I know the answer to this limit is supposed to be 1 following the conjugate method, yet why do I get minus infinite doing this the other way?

Recall that $\sqrt {x^2}=|x|$

You are doing $\sqrt{x^2A}= x\sqrt{A}$. That's wrong.

Note that when $x$ is negative, $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$ (for instance, if $x = -5$, then $\sqrt{(-5)^2} = \sqrt{25} = 5 = -(-5)$). Therefore, in the last step you should have written
$$x\left(\color{red}-\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3}{x^2}}+1\right),$$
instead of what you wrote. But now when $x$ tends to $-\infty$ you get the indetermination $\infty \cdot 0$.

The Problem:
So, in your work, you have done the operation
$$
\sqrt{x^2 \left( 1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2} \right) }
\stackrel ? =
\sqrt{x^2} \sqrt{ 1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2}}
\stackrel ? =
x \sqrt{ 1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2}}
$$
Firstly, actually, the second equality should have $|x|$ on the outside as
$$
\sqrt{x^2} = |x|
$$
for real $x$. ($\sqrt{x^2} \ne x$; what happens if $x=-1$ for instance?)
So we really should have
$$
\sqrt{x^2 \left( 1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2} \right) }
=
|x| \sqrt{ 1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2}}
$$
However, even this results in problems - because it messes up your subsequent factoring. You were trying to factor,
$$
x \sqrt{1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2} } + x
\stackrel ? =
x \left(  \sqrt{ 1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2}} + 1 \right)
$$
but notice that, in reality, since we have
$$
|x| \sqrt{1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2} } + x 
$$
matters have become a tad more complicated.

Rescuing It:
But this can be salvaged! Since you want a limit as $x \to -\infty$, just focus on what happens when $x<0$. Then $|x|=-x$, so
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to -\infty} |x| \sqrt{1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2} } + x 
&= 
\lim_{x \to -\infty} -x \sqrt{1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2} } + x \\
&= 
\lim_{x \to -\infty} x \left( - \sqrt{1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2} } + 1 \right)
\end{align*}$$
Call this limit $L$; notice it takes a $\infty \cdot 0$ indeterminate form. Then you can apply L'Hopital's rule:
$$
L = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\displaystyle - \sqrt{1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2} } + 1}{\displaystyle \frac 1 x}
$$
turns it into an $\infty/\infty$ form. We get
$$
L = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\displaystyle \left( \frac{3-x}{x^3  \sqrt{ 1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2} }} \right)}{\displaystyle - \frac{1}{x^2} }
 =   \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x-3}{x} \frac{1}{  \sqrt{ 1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2} }}  
= 1
$$
Though honestly I'd have just prefer the conjugate method right from the start since the derivative of the numerator is a tad annoying to calculate in my opinion (easy, but tedious).

Some Graphs, Because Why Not:
To see matters perhaps a bit more visually:
Here's the graph of $\sqrt{x^2-2x+3} + x$:

In blue, we now overlay your factorization, $x \left( \sqrt{ 1 - \frac 2 x + \frac{3}{x^2} } + 1 \right)$:

Notice the lack of agreement for $x<0$! But if we instead swap the sign on the radical, we get agreement for $x<0$, which as commented previously is "good enough" for a limit where $x \to -\infty$:


Thank you so much, PrincessEev, for the detailedness of your answer, taking the time and effort to explain everything so thoroughly and even draw the graphs.

Complete the square in the radicand. Thus
$\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+2}.$
And then
$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+2}+(x-1)=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+2}-(x-1)}\to0,x\to-\infty,$
as the denominator is the sum of two terms that both go to $+\infty$. So
$\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+x=[\sqrt{(x-1)^2+2}+(x-1)]+1\to0+1=1.$

As noticed the given limit is an indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$ indeed
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}=\sqrt {x^2}\sqrt{1-2/x+3/x^2}\to \infty \cdot 1=\infty$$
since $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, this is where you went wrong with the alternative way.
To avoid confusion one effective way is to let $y=-x\to \infty$ then
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}+x=\lim_{y\to\infty}\sqrt{y^2+2y+3}-y$$
and use that
$$\sqrt{y^2+2y+3}-y=\sqrt{y^2+2y+3}-y\frac{\sqrt{y^2+2y+3}+y}{\sqrt{y^2+2y+3}+y}=\frac{2y+3}{\sqrt{y^2+2y+3}+y}$$

For all intents and purposes, OP made it clear they did the limit via this method already, and was wondering why their alternative method didn't work.

@PrincessEev Yes you are right, I give the dvice in the comment but I should repeat it here! I add that
